# Selenium Webdriver cannot find the element that has javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

Please help with my problem. `Selenium Webdriver` cannot locate this element that has dropdown and being controlled by `javascript`.

[image]

This is what should happen, clicking the dropdown should show an input text and will autosearch for what you have searched

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the element is dynamically generated when the button is clicked.

You will first need to click on `span.select2-arrow`. Then the search filter appears and you should be able to send text to `input.select2-input`.